# How do you combine two foreach loops into one

Tags: php, foreach

The language is PHP. I have one foreach ( $a as $b) and another foreach ($c as $d => $e). How do i combine them to read as one. I tired foreach (($a as $b) && ($c as $d => $e)), but that is rubbish.

Answer (score 26):

You might be interested in [SPL's MultipleIterator](http://docs.php.net/class.multipleiterator)

e.g.

```
// ArrayIterator is just an example, could be any Iterator.
$a1 = new ArrayIterator(array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6));
$a2 = new ArrayIterator(array(11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16));

$it = new MultipleIterator;
$it->attachIterator($a1);
$it->attachIterator($a2);

foreach($it as $e) {
  echo $e[0], ' | ', $e[1], "\n";
}
```

prints

```
1 | 11
2 | 12
3 | 13
4 | 14
5 | 15
6 | 16
```

Comment: That's the most interesting peace of code I've seen today. Plus one for that. Do the arrays HAVE to be of equal length, or do you stop iterating on just one of them at some point?

Comment: That depends on whether you set the MultipleIterator::MIT_NEED_ANY or MultipleIterator::MIT_NEED_ALL flag. With MIT_NEED_ALL the iterator stops if any of the inner iterators has no more elements. With MIT_NEED_ANY the iterator continues as long as at least one inner iterator has another element, all other items become NULL. MIT_NEED_ALL is the default.

Comment: Thank you for introducing this SPL feature! Plus one too!

Comment: Just came across this - Looks like this is for PHP 5.3.0+. I'm running  5.2.17, is there an alternative for that version of PHP?

Answer (score 11):

1) First method

```
<?php
$FirstArray = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd');
$SecondArray = array('1', '2', '3', '4');

foreach(array_combine($FirstArray, $SecondArray) as $f => $n) {
    echo $f.$n;
    echo "<br/>";
}
?>
```

or 2) Second method

```
<?php
$FirstArray = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd');
$SecondArray = array('1', '2', '3', '4');

for ($index = 0 ; $index < count($FirstArray); $index ++) {
  echo $FirstArray[$index] . $SecondArray[$index];
  echo "<br/>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand what you're trying to do. If you want to reach them one after the other just use two loops:

```
foreach ($a as $b) { ... }
foreach ($c as $d => $e) { ... }
```

If you want all combinations from `$a` and `$c`:

```
foreach ($a as $b) {
  foreach ($c as $d => $e) {
    // do stuff
  }
}
```

I guess you could do something like:

```
foreach (array_merge($a, $c) as $k => $v) {
  ...
}
```

but I wouldn't necessarily advise it.

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you want I think.  It will be advance both arrays equally at the same time throughout your loop.  You can always `break` manually if `$c` is a different size than `$a` and you need breaking logic based on array size:

```
foreach($a as $b)
{
    list($d,$e) = each($c);
    //continue on with $b, $d and $e all set
}
```

`each()` will advance the array pointer of `$c` on each iteration.