# How to create the foreach correct with 2 arrays

Tags: php, foreach

I extracted the values from a file .html and now I'd like to create a table.
Example file .html:

```html
<tr>
  <td>
    <div class="title">Title</div>
    <img src="images.jpg" />
    <div class="other">Other value</div>
  </td>
  <td>
    <div class="title">Title2</div>
    <img src="images2.jpg" />
    <div class="other">Other value2</div>
  </td>
  <td>
    <div class="title">Title3</div>
    <img src="images3.jpg" />
    <div class="other">Other value3</div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

I have 3 variables:

```
$other = isset($matches1[1]) ? $matches1[1] : '';
$title = isset($matches2[1]) ? $matches2[1] : '';
$img = isset($matches3[1]) ? $matches3[1] : '';
```

For example, if I wanted to show all the titles, I'd use a foreach:

```
foreach($title as $titles) {
    echo '<li>' . $titles . '</li>';
}
```

But now, I want show all values in a "td": each "td" must have: the title, the "other" value and the image.

```
echo '<td>' . $title . $other . ' <img src="' . $img .'" /></td>';
```

The foreach isn't good. How can I?

---

I used the second method and it works => https://stackoverflow.com/a/15677443/2158434

Comment: What happens or what's wrong with your existing code and output?

Comment: I edited the original post, so now there are more information.

Answer (score 1):

You can use e.g. SPL's [MultipleIterator](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/class.multipleiterator.php) for that.

e.g.

```
<?php
$matches = [
    1 => [ 'a','b','c'],
    2 => [ 'A','B','C', 'D'],
    3 => [ 'I', 'II', 'III' ]
];

$it = new MultipleIterator(MultipleIterator::MIT_NEED_ANY);
$it->attachIterator( new ArrayIterator($matches[1]));
$it->attachIterator( new ArrayIterator($matches[2]));
$it->attachIterator( new ArrayIterator($matches[3]));

foreach($it as $e) {
    printf("%s %s %s\r\n", $e[0], $e[1], $e[2]);
}
```

prints

```
a A I
b B II
c C III
 D
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay... I just don't get why you need `foreach` for that.

IMHO, you should use a simple `for` loop:

```
for($i = 0, $len = sizeof($title); $i < $len; $i++) {
    echo '<td>' . $title[i] . $other[i] . ' <img src="' . $img[i] .'" /></td>';
}
```

Of course, **I'm assuming your 3 arrays have the same size**.